# Google Maps API changed

Tags: maps, google

Did anyone have problems with Google Maps API? I have an HTML with OpenLayers and Geoserver. Since yesterday, the Google Maps Hybrid map is not working, even if some images are loaded in Firebug. Sometimes I receive a message stating Google Maps API v3.2 is deprecated.

```
 var map, info;

    function load() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",allOverlays: true, projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    layers: [
       // new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite",{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels:50}),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Hybrid",{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels:20}),
        cladiri=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Cladiri",
                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/proprietati/wms",
                {layers: 'proprietati:<?php echo "".$identificator."_cladiri";?>',transparent: true, format: 'image/png'},
                {isBaseLayer: true, opacity: 0.9, singleTile: true})
    ],
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(26.1473586305531, 44.4431676053183).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")),
    zoom: 15
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, not having any issues with Google Maps, including Hybrid.  Maybe you could try using the current version of the API from Google's SVN?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

Comment: I changed the js. Still not working. I will put my code in question. The strange thing is that in firebug some images from google hybrid are loading.

Comment: Ok - it does appear likely that the API changed in a way that broke OpenLayers, and was forecast according this ( https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/issues/1450 ), which mentions 3.20 will be deprecated and 3.21 causes an issue in OpenLayers. OpenLayers looks like it has been changed to handle this, but in the master branch, not the CDN (see the very last comment).  Looks like this is your workaround - get the latest OpenLayers.js from the master branch, save it on your web server, update your page(s) to point to your locally hosted version and this issue hopefully will be resolved.

Comment: I use openlayers 2.13.1. Got to go to 3 :)

Comment: Simple solution - changed Google Maps to Bing maps.